# Reconstruct object based on key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have let's say this object

```
const data = {
    'name-pl': 'something pl',
    'name-en': 'something en',
    'name-de': 'something de',
    'content-pl': 'some content pl',
    'content-en': 'some content en',
    'content-de': 'some content de',
    category: 'animals',
  };
```

And this array

```
const array = ['name', 'content']
```

Now based on values in array I want to reconstruct this object into this:

```
const data = {
    name:{
      pl: 'something pl',
      en: 'something en',
      de: 'something de',
    },
    content:{
      pl:'some content pl',
      en:'some content en',
      de:'some content de',
    },
    category: 'animals'
  }
```

So if the value in array matches key in original object this happens, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes),

- Go through each key of the object,
- Split the key into its two parts,
- If the first part is in `array` create a new sub-object with its name, and place the second part inside it.
- If not leave it as it is and move on.

**Demo:**

```js
const data = {
  'name-pl': 'something pl',
  'name-en': 'something en',
  'name-de': 'something de',
  'content-pl': 'some content pl',
  'content-en': 'some content en',
  'content-de': 'some content de',
  category: 'animals',
};

const array = ['name', 'content']

let result = {}

for (let key in data) {
  let [prefix, suffix] = key.split("-")
  if (array.includes(prefix)) {
    result[prefix] =  {...result[prefix], [suffix]: data[key]}
  }
  else {
    result[key] = data[key]
  }
}

console.log(result)
```